# Spring Boot Custom rest API controller based on properties file or a filter

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I need to implement a token based authentication(permitAll)+ authorization(based on token and a private key) in a spring boot REST API.I am using a properties file which enables or disables the token based security depending on the value of the properties file.
token.sec.active = true/false

If the value is true then the controller should asked for token in @requestHeader and if it is false then it shouldn't.
Is it possible to do this without having to write two different controllers?
Any leads would be helpful.
thanks

Comment: @RequestHeader(required="${token.sec.active}")

Comment: Thanks, It was that simple.Please answer so that I can upvote you!

Comment: Hey, But Spring boot says that this value must be constant expression,It is not allowing me to have a variable there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, okay, otherwise you can just set @RequestHeader(required = false, value="token")
and then implement the logic for missing header in the controller method itself.

EDIT: if you would Autowire value token.sec.active to your controller.